# Magento import product by new extension

Tags: magento

I am creating new extension module in magento. I am created some dropdown attribute in magento. I want to insert values from my extension module to magento. It accepts text, text area fields. But could not get for multiple select and dropdown. any idea?

Comment: Show us what you tried so far and show us what you've done for research on this to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

To attach value for select or multiple select attribute, you need to know ID of Manage Option (value of your select or multiple select attribute)